# How to handle functions as arguments when they point to a function

Tags: c++

Sorry the question is ambiguous but i am not sure what Terminology i should use.

The function in main.cpp is:

```
Onetime("see the dentist", Date(2013, 9, 4), Time(11, 30, 0), Time(12, 30, 0));
```

I have functions to handle Date() and Time().

```
Onetime(string s, ...)
```

The first argument is a string but i am not sure how to handle the other three arguments.

Comment: Those are most likely constructors: `Onetime(std::string s, Date, Time, Time)`? (perhaps `const&`, depending on what the function does)

Answer (score 0):

As your `Date(2013, 9, 4), Time(11, 30, 0), Time(12, 30, 0)` first of all evaluate and construct 3 objects of type `Date` `Time` `Time` you need to have reference to those types in your prototype. So it should look like this:

```
Onetime(string s, Date& d, Time& t1, Time& t2);
```

you could also omite the `&` but then your code will be slover as CopyConstructors for `d` `t1`and `t2` will be called whenever `Onetime`is called.